# Delphi regex replace inconsistent behavior

Tags: regex, delphi, regexp-replace

I have below code.

```
  var
  result := 'DECLARE''' + #13#10 + 'DECLARE''''';
  result := TRegEx.Replace(result, '\A\s*DECLARE''\s*', 'abc', [roIgnoreCase]);
  ShowMessage(result);
```

When I run it, I got:

[image]

This result is expected. However, when I change the replacement string to an empty string, like this:

```
  result := 'DECLARE''' + #13#10 + 'DECLARE''''';
  result := TRegEx.Replace(result, '\A\s*DECLARE''\s*', '', [roIgnoreCase]);

  ShowMessage(result);
```

I got this result when run the program:

[image]

Why this happens? I only want to replace the first match, and that's why I use `\A` to anchor the regex at the beginning of the string.

Comment: So, `\A` works as `(?m)^`, it looks like a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you get the results you get is because [TRegEx.Replace](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.RegularExpressions.TRegEx.Replace) replaces all matches in an Input string with a Replacement string.

If you want to replace only the first match then you need to use overloaded version of `TRegEx.Replace` that allows you to also pass the Count parameter with which you can control of how many occurrences gets replaced.

Since this overloaded version of `TRegEx.Replace` is declared as regular function belonging to `TRegEx` record and not as `class function` you will first have to declare variable of TRegEx record and set Pattern and Options using [TRegEx.Create](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.RegularExpressions.TRegEx.Create) and then call appropriate overloaded version of `Replace`.

So your code should look like this:

```
var RegEx: TRegEx;

result := 'DECLARE''' + #13#10 + 'DECLARE''''';
RegEx := TRegEx.Create('\A\s*DECLARE''\s*', [roIgnoreCase]);
Result := RegEx.Replace(Result,'abc',1);
ShowMessage(result);

result := 'DECLARE''' + #13#10 + 'DECLARE''''';
RegEx := TRegEx.Create('\A\s*DECLARE''\s*', [roIgnoreCase]);
Result := RegEx.Replace(Result,'',1);
ShowMessage(result);
```

This then returns `abcDECLARE''` for `abc` replacement string and `DECLARE''` for empty replacement string.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your solution works. However, in my question, the `\A` part of the regex should only replace from the beginning of the string, even you replace all the matches. The behavior still looks weird to me.

Comment: That is because for replace it runs against the full modified string to find the next match. Once the first DECLARE' is replaced the second is now just whitespace away from the start of the string so it now matches and gets replaced as well.